# How can I fill complement of two sets A and B knowing that A is subset of B with venndiagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I want to fill

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-2.3,-2.3) rectangle (2.3,2.3);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=gray,fill opacity=0.5] (0.,0.) ellipse (1.5 cm and 2.cm);
\draw [rotate around={0.:(0.,0.)},color=black,fill=white] (0.,0.) ellipse (1.cm and 1.3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I fill complement of two sets A and B knowing that A is subset of B with venndiagram?

Comment: @Zarko I think, my case is different from your show link. My question is A is a subset of B.

Comment: (i) answers in given link contain a lot of examples which can serve to draw yours (ii) your *mwe* already show desired result (so far you choose a white fill for subset, but this is easy to change to different color).